# Parsing XMLString with libxml2 in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, libxml2

I have an `XML` which is in the form of a string which my parser can't work with. Concretely it has all the XML tags but it is a string instead of an XML file. It should be first converted to an `XML` file. I have already googled and came across a similar question on SO but that deals with libxml2's C++ api. I am working in python.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is (a) based on the false premise that you need to write XML to a file; and (b) writing to a file is not specific to XML.

Answer (score 3):

`libxml2` can parse strings that contain `xml`.

```
import libxml2
libxml2.parseDoc('<?xml version="1.0"?> <data> <something>Baaahh!</something> </data>')
```

this returns a valid `xml` object.

If you want to read a whole file you can use `libxml2.parseFile`